# Get week range between two given dates in php

Tags: php, date

I have a requirement to display data in day,week and month(group by)

User selects from and to date, Now I want to find out the weeks between that date.

Example:

If user selects,

From: `2014-07-01` to To: `2014-07-23`

Now I want to week dates like this:

```
2014-07-01 to 2014-07-05 ,
2014-07-06 to 2014-07-12,
2014-07-13 to 2014-07-19 , 
2014-07-20 to 2014-07-23.
```

If I have this dates range, I can sum up totals between these dates and show it as weekly sum.

Thanks in advance, 
Cheers, 
Kiran

Answer (score 2):

Check with below:

```
<?php
$date1 = '2014-07-01';
$date2 = '2014-07-23';

$weekDiff = date('W', strtotime($date2)) - date('W', strtotime($date1));
```

Comment: No.. It outputs just 3.